# Error de sintaxis en Mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo una consulta en Mysql y en un testeador de sintaxis memarca que tengo un error pero no me doy cuenta cual es. Alguno que lo detecte_ Gracias!

Consulta,

```
$sqlConsorcio = "SELECT p.uf, 
                        p.nombreyapellido, 
                        p.deuda_ant, 
                        p.exp_actual, 
                        p.punitorios, 
                        p.total, 
                        c.nombre_consorcio 
                 FROM  prop_inq AS p 
                 INNER JOIN consorcio AS c 
                 ON p.id_consorcio = c.id_consorcio 
                 WHERE id_consorcio = $consorcioSeleccionado"
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar por favor el mensaje de error que obtienes?

Comment: Prueba a poner un apostrofe ( ' ) en vez de comillas dobles ( " )

Answer (score 0):

```
            SELECT 
                p.uf AS uf,
                p.nombreyapellido AS nombre,
                p.deuda_ant AS deuda,
                p.exp_actual AS actual,
                p.punitorios AS unitarios,
                p.total,
                c.nombre_consorcio
            FROM
                prop_inq p
                    INNER JOIN
                consorcio c ON p.id_consorcio = c.id_consorcio
            WHERE
                id_consorcio = $consorcioSeleccionado
```

la palabra reservada AS se usa para los alias de los campos de las tablas, no para las tablas.

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta está bien pero te pasaron dos cosas, en id_consorcio tenes que identificar a que tabla hace referencia y tu variable, que supongo que debe ser en php tiene que estar separada.

Quedandote así en el código:

```
$sqlConsorcio = "SELECT p.uf, 
                        p.nombreyapellido, 
                        p.deuda_ant, 
                        p.exp_actual, 
                        p.punitorios, 
                        p.total, 
                        c.nombre_consorcio 
                 FROM  prop_inq AS p 
                 INNER JOIN consorcio AS c 
                 ON p.id_consorcio = c.id_consorcio 
                 WHERE p.id_consorcio = " . $consorcioSeleccionado
```

Saludos!

Comment: Funciona perfecto con ese cambio! nota positiva!